# Unity3D [2D] Spawning monsters from a pre-defined place is inconsistent

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a small problem which makes my game be inconsistent and annoying. I've made a video to show it in action as it will be a wall of text to try to explain here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=724qdit375U&feature=youtu.be

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CircleCollider2D))]

public class PlaceMonster : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject monsterPrefab;
    private GameObject monster;
    private GameManagerBehavior gameManager;

    void Start ()
    {
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManagerBehavior>();
    }

    void Update ()
    {

    }

    private bool canPlaceMonster()
    {
        int cost = monsterPrefab.GetComponent<MonsterData> ().levels[0].cost;
        return monster == null && gameManager.Gold >= cost;
    }

    void OnMouseUp ()
    {
        if (canPlaceMonster ())
        {
            monster = (GameObject) Instantiate(monsterPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            gameManager.Gold -= monster.GetComponent<MonsterData>().CurrentLevel.cost;
        }
        else if (canUpgradeMonster())
        {
            monster.GetComponent<MonsterData>().increaseLevel();

            gameManager.Gold -= monster.GetComponent<MonsterData>().CurrentLevel.cost;
        }
    }

    private bool canUpgradeMonster()
    {
        if (monster != null)
        {
            MonsterData monsterData = monster.GetComponent<MonsterData> ();
            MonsterLevel nextLevel = monsterData.getNextLevel();
            if (nextLevel != null) {
                return gameManager.Gold >= nextLevel.cost;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the code for the spawner.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class MonsterLevel {
  public int cost;
  public GameObject visualization;
  public GameObject bullet;
  public float fireRate;
}

public class MonsterData : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<MonsterLevel> levels;
    private MonsterLevel currentLevel;
    public MonsterLevel CurrentLevel {
        get {
            return currentLevel;
        }
        set {
            currentLevel = value;
            int currentLevelIndex = levels.IndexOf(currentLevel);

            GameObject levelVisualization = levels[currentLevelIndex].visualization;
            for (int i = 0; i < levels.Count; i++) {
                if (levelVisualization != null) {
                    if (i == currentLevelIndex) {
                        levels[i].visualization.SetActive(true);
                    } else {
                        levels[i].visualization.SetActive(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void OnEnable() {
        CurrentLevel = levels[0];
    }

    public MonsterLevel getNextLevel() {
        int currentLevelIndex = levels.IndexOf (currentLevel);
        int maxLevelIndex = levels.Count - 1;
        if (currentLevelIndex < maxLevelIndex) {
            return levels[currentLevelIndex+1];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void increaseLevel() {
        int currentLevelIndex = levels.IndexOf(currentLevel);
        if (currentLevelIndex < levels.Count - 1) {
            CurrentLevel = levels[currentLevelIndex + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code for the tower itself that gets spawned.

Basically my spots which place those things sometimes work and sometimes don't.

It's random which will work. Sometimes I'll be able to upgrade 3 monsters to max level, sometimes I'll be able to get 7 to level 3 and the others won't spawn at all. I have no idea why it is causing this. I have made **layers** and I have played a lot around with the Eit>  Projects settings > Physics 2D options to make things NOT interact with each other. I have tried a lot of combinations of things and nothing works.

Comment: We would prefer you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Posting external links is generally frowned upon because when the link goes dead, this post is useless.

Comment: Done. Sorry for this, I didn't know before.

Comment: Well, there is (at least) one NullReferenceException showing at the bottom.  Even if that is not related to this problem, it should fixed. To check if there is a problem with proper collision boxes (hitting the correct ones) I'd say, you put a Debug.Log at the beginning of  PlaceMonster::OnMouseUp() to see if the correct one is actually clicked.

Comment: Gunnar B, do you mean infront of

 void OnMouseUp ()
    {
        if (canPlaceMonster ())

?

 If yes, where exactly as I get errors...

Comment: void onMouseUp() { Debug.Log(something useful); if(canPlaceMonster())... }

Comment: Another thing I noticed (if I saw it correctly) is, that most of your Openspot objects have their name in red (in the list) which means that they are not associated with a prefab properly. I don't know if that is intended.